# div background-image: need help with code

Tags: html, background, png

If you Firebug this page: http://www.radiumhosting.com/web-hosting/vps-cloud-hosting look at the VPS cloud slider. The background image isn't fully behind the border to the right of the Storage tab.

I added this to the end of the code to place the image on the background:

```
<div style="margin: -229pt 0pt 0pt -20pt;">
<div style="background-image: url(/images/stories/cloud-background2.png); height: 315px; width:   710px;"></div> 
</div>
```

Compatibility View in IE9 allows the image to be displayed on top of most elements. What should I change?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use new `div`'s for the background. Just add the `.cloudbackground` class to `<div class="rt-block">`. Then use the HTML and CSS code below instead:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="rt-block cloudbackground">
```

**CSS:**

```
.cloudbackground {
    background: url("/images/stories/cloud-background2.png") no-repeat;
}
```

This will fix all your issues including making it work in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [z-index CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) with a negative value.